# Newbie needs installation help

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu onto an old Dell laptop from a USB stick and chose the dual option of using Windows Xp or Ubuntu during the installation options.

I then allocated about 50:50 partition drive space using the slider. So far so good. I then chose to install updates during the installation and pressed install.

Everything seemed to be installing ok Until it seemed to get stuck - I left it for about 10 hours reading somewhere else that it can take time to install. After this time I decided to shut down the computer and see if I could install again only this time the dual boot option was missing. I removed the USB stick and rebooted but now all I get is a black screen with a flashing prompt.

Have I lost my Windows Xp?

Is there something I can do to get things back to normal?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to allocate unassigned space within Windows XP beforehand, I do not believe doing so in the Ubuntu installer will work when the goal is to dual boot.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you lost windows XP , when you were trying to dual boot , from windows you need to allocate some space for ubuntu and then install ubuntu on that freespace ,  as you changed the partition to 50:50 using slider , you are disturbing the windows partitions thereby you lose your windows and it does not functions as it did previously , when trying to dual boot necessary steps have to be followed carefully .

Try this :
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Do you really mean you hope the OP has lost Windows XP?